# How to sort a CSV string based on the inner values?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this CSV String

```
"B,C,D,A,E\n18945,12091,14058,2907,15132\n25,122,134,428,211"
```

**which I have separated by `\n` and `,` and got below array**:

**I have this array**:

```
[["B", "C", "D", "A", "E"], ["18945", "12091", "14058", "2907", "15132"], ["25", "122", "134", "428", "211"]]
```

where first array inside the main array is indicating the column names, which I need to sort alphabetically based on that the remaining arrays should also sorted.

**Consider a table like this**:

```
B -> 18945 -> 25
```

**After sort, I am expecting an output like this**:

```
[["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], ["2907", "18945", "12091", "14058", "15132"], ["428", "25", "122", "134", "211"]]
```

Comment: Sorry but for me your question is totally unclear. What is the expected result?

Comment: That's a very unwieldy structure for this task. How did you end up here? The array should at least be transposed, or better, make your own struct. What data is this supposed to represent?

Comment: Just updated my question with expected output. @LeoDabus

Comment: I have to sort a csv string data. @Sweeper

Comment: @Hemang Not a direct answer to your question but you should structure your data

Comment: Exactly as Leo said, you should parse CSV file to an array of (codable) structs,. Use something like [this](https://github.com/dehesa/CodableCSV) for example.

Comment: @Sweeper just updated my question with additional details, sure, let me check the link you shared.

Comment: @Sweeper, I think I will not require that library as long as I am also able to part and separate the CSV string values. Right ?

Comment: Oh you want to sort it by _column_? That link won't help then, but the advice remains the same - read the CSV into _structs_, not arrays, then sort the structs as you usually do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should try to structure your data but if you really want to go through this path you just need to sort the first collection indices and map the collections using the sorted indices. Of course this assumes all collections have the same number of elements and the collection is not empty:

```
let table = [["B", "C", "D", "A", "E"], ["18945", "12091", "14058", "2907", "15132"], ["25", "122", "134", "428", "211"]]

let indices = table[0].indices.sorted { table[0][$0] < table[0][$1] }

let sorted = table.map { collection in
    indices.map { collection[$0] }
}
```

---

If you want to be extra paranoid and make sure your code will never crash you can get the first collection using if let and use compact map checking if the collection contains each index before accessing them using subscript:

---

```
let table = [["B", "C", "D", "A", "E"], ["18945", "12091", "14058", "2907", "15132"], ["25", "122", "134", "428", "211"]]
if let columns = table.first {
    let indices = columns.indices.sorted { columns[$0] < columns[$1] }
    let sorted = table.map { collection in
        indices.compactMap { collection.indices ~= $0 ? collection[$0] : nil }
    }
    print(sorted)
}
```

---

**edit/update**:

For a case insensitive sort:

```
let indices = columns.indices.sorted { columns[$0].caseInsensitiveCompare(columns[$1]) == .orderedAscending }
```

For a case and diacritic insensitive sort:

```
let indices = columns.indices.sorted { columns[$0].localizedStandardCompare(columns[$1]) == .orderedAscending }
```

---

This will print

> [["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], ["2907", "18945", "12091", "14058", "15132"], ["428", "25", "122", "134", "211"]]

Comment: Thanks Leo, when you don't know how many arrays inside it, how would you do that?

Comment: In my case, all the collection will have same number of elements but I don't know how many collections are there.

Comment: @Hemang I don't know how many arrays are inside your initial array. My only assumption is that they have the same number of elements as the first array.

Comment: Leo, you are a gem man, this is working for n number of collections. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hey, Leo, with respect to your above solution, anyways to sort the headers (first array) using  case insensitive technique?